# What is the difference between Boolean Algebra and Boolean Lattice?

Tags: algebra

What is the difference between Boolean Algebra and Boolean Lattice? I have already searched on Google but could not find a reasonable answer?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(structure)), these are two names for the same concept. You can differentiate them by stating that Boolean algebra is an algebraic structure having operations $\land,\lor,\lnot$ satisfying certain axioms, and in contrast a Boolean lattice is a lattice having certain properties; but the two definitions are equivalent. Sometimes Boolean algebra and Boolean lattice refer to specific constructions (subsets of a set), but according to [Stone's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras) these two definitions are also equivalent.